# Capifony deploy with symfony2 not including my Bundles

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, amazon-ec2, capifony

I'm trying to deploy my symfony2 project to amazon ec2 but seems like it's not deploying my custom bundles.

I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyCompany\MainBundle\MainBundle' not found in /var/www/html/releases/20120901100611/app/AppKernel.php on line 20

All the vendors bundles are installed. What's my error?